# Animation Graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a live_graph with matplotlib. I got two issues:
First, I have the error:
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, len(my_entry), i + 1)
Second: The graph showing up with unexpected line.
Here is the data in Working_Out_data1.txt file which you see in the codes[image]

```
PART0, 1, 1.5
PART1, 1, 2.5
PART2, 1, 3.5
PART3, 1, 4.5
PART4, 1, 5.5
PART0, 2, 1.6
PART1, 2, 2.6
PART2, 2, 3.6
PART3, 2, 4.6
PART4, 2, 5.6
PART0, 3, 1.3
PART1, 3, 2.3
PART2, 3, 3.3
PART3, 3, 4.3
PART4, 3, 5.3
PART0, 4, 2.0
PART1, 4, 3.0
PART2, 4, 4.0
PART3, 4, 5.0
PART4, 4, 6.0
PART0, 5, 1.0
PART1, 5, 2.0
PART2, 5, 3.0
PART3, 5, 4.0
PART4, 5, 5.0
```

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
var_list = ['PART0', 'PART1', 'PART2', 'PART3', 'PART4']
my_entry = []
for _ in range(len(var_list)):
    my_entry.append([])


def get_data(data_string, item_loc):
    temp = data_string.split(item_loc)
    if len(temp) >= 2:
        return temp[1]


def animate(i):
    lines = open("Working_Out_data1.txt", "r").read()
    line1 = lines.split('\n')
    line1.pop(-1)
    # print(line1)
    for line_graph in line1:
        for var in var_list:
            if var in line_graph:
                my_entry[var_list.index(var)].append(get_data(line_graph, var + ', '))
    # print(my_entry)
    # input(">")
    for i in range(len(my_entry)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, len(my_entry), i + 1)
        ax.clear()
        x = []
        y = []
        for item in my_entry[i]:
            values = item.split(', ')
            x.append(int(values[0]))
            y.append(float(values[1]))
        ax.plot(x, y, color='green', marker='o', markersize= 8)
        my_axes.append(ax)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you looked into [Plotly Animations](https://plotly.com/python/animations/)?

Comment: I did but how to fix the issue?